# Understanding the CIP configuration for cyclic substituents with hetero-oxygen atoms

Tags: nomenclature, stereochemistry

[image]

As per CIP sequence rules, the topmost $\ce{C}$ on the left gets 1st priority. Moving on to the right side of the double bond, we have:

Top $\ce{C}$: ($\ce{C}$,$\ce{O}$,$\ce{O}$,$\ce{H}$)
Bottom $\ce{C}$: ($\ce{C}$,$\ce{O}$,$\ce{O}$,$\ce{H}$,$\ce{C}$...)

Thus bottom $\ce{C}$ gets priority one on the right side.

Now, since 1st priorities are opposite, it's an E isomer. But the solution manual states that it's a Z isomer. Why is my method incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

CIP rules for **cyclic substituents** are different. See 
[this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/88893/confusion-in-cip-priority-rules-cyclic-substituents) for the rules. (The rules are given in the question itself).

This will be the **hierarchical digraph** for the right side of the molecule.

[image] [image]

The atoms encircled are the ghost atoms. From the digraph one can see why the compound is **Z**.